# Accessing functions in jQuery function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a really stupid question - I'm having trouble accessing a function defined within `$(document).ready(...)` since it is bound to that functional scope, and wondering if there is a way to do so(perhaps by using some sort of shared service, etc)?

Basically, I created a preload function that is outside of the `$(document).ready(...)` block, and after it finishes preloading, it should execute a callback function (which is defined within the `$(document).ready()` block).

```
preload(['http://www.kidstartnow.com/images/carousel_offers_2.jpg', 'http://www.kidstartnow.com/images/carousel_offers_3.jpg'], function(len) {
    sayLength(len);   
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TVwa/1/

This seems related to the problem of different scopes between two `$(document).ready(...)` scopes. What is the best way to access the variables in another `$(document).ready(...)` scope (the use case would be let's say I had several different functions stored in different files, and each function used jQuery, wouldn't I need to wrap a `$(document).ready(...)` for each file?
http://jsfiddle.net/qu79j/

Comment: The simplest solution is to not declare sayLength in a ready callback.

Comment: Move the `sayLength` function outside of the document ready handler.

Comment: Or pass the callback function as a parameter to the `preload` function, if you don't waht `sayLength` in your global scope

Comment: If I don't declare sayLength in a ready callback, can I still use jQuery selectors $('xxx')?

Comment: @DanTang Yes you can.

Comment: @DanTang Yes you can, It's scoped higher meaning you can use it inside and outside of the documentReady which is where I imagine your selectors will be

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't know that........

Comment: Of course !! your selector musn't select elements that are dynamicly generated by JS before the document is ready. Otherwise, you can't be sure that the element is already created when calling the selector.